# RoboCopy Directory Sizing with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory, size, subdirectory, robocopy

I am attempting to get a report of only the sub-directories in my root folder. I am receiving two errors when attempting to do this.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:1
+ $fldSize = (robocopy $DIR "NO" /e /l /r:0 /w:0 /nfl /ndl /nc /fp /np  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:6 char:1
+ $DIR + " = " + "{0:N2}" -f ($fldSize / 1MB) + " MB"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I've done a bit of looking, and what I have found seems to indicate an array problem, however nothing I have tried thus far has yielded any different results. Script is below.

```
function get_dir ($SDIR){
$colItems = Get-ChildItem $SDIR -Directory
foreach ($DIR in $colItems)
{
$fldSize = (robocopy $DIR "NO" /e /l /r:0 /w:0 /nfl /ndl /nc /fp /np /njh /xj /bytes| ? {$_ -match "Bytes :"}).trim().split(" ")[2]
$DIR + " = " + "{0:N2}" -f ($fldSize / 1MB) + " MB"
}
}


get_dir C:\TEST\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to use `$DIR.fullname` as each element in `$colitems` is of type `DirectoryInfo` and you cannot treat it as a string to create your result as you do in the line of code after the robocopy.

Here is a fixed version

```
function get_dir ($SDIR)
{
    $colItems = Get-ChildItem $SDIR -Directory
    foreach ($DIR in $colItems)
    {
        $fldSize = (robocopy $DIR.fullname "NO" /e /l /r:0 /w:0 /nfl /ndl /nc /fp /np /njh /xj /bytes| ? {$_ -match "Bytes :"}).trim().split(" ")[2]
        $DIR.fullname + " = " + ("{0:N2}" -f ($fldSize / 1MB) + " MB")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I knew I was missing something, and your explanation helped me not only understand what I was missing but why it was necessary.